# Javapns give InvalidDeviceTokenFormatException

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using Java PNS to send notification. However, i'm getting the follwoing error:

```
javapns.devices.exceptions.InvalidDeviceTokenFormatException: Device Token has a length of [140] and not the required 64 bytes!eror has occusred:Device Token has a length of [140] and not the required 64 bytes!

        at javapns.devices.implementations.basic.BasicDevice.validateTokenFormat(BasicDevice.java:67)
        at javapns.devices.implementations.basic.BasicDevice.<init>(BasicDevice.java:49)
        at javapns.devices.implementations.basic.BasicDevice.<init>(BasicDevice.java:37)
```

this how I created my device list:

```
List<Device> newList = new ArrayList<Device>();
            Iterator<String> tempItr = v.iterator();
            while (tempItr.hasNext()) {
                String myDeviceToken = (String) (vItr.next());
                try {
                    BasicDevice device = new BasicDevice(myDeviceToken);

                    newList.add(device);

                } catch (Exception e) { // error=2; // notification issue
                    System.out.println("eror has occusred:" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
```

any clue why it's giving invalid token format:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong :

```
String myDeviceToken = (String) (vItr.next());
```

It should be :

```
String myDeviceToken = vItr.next().getToken();
```

EDIT : I was assuming that v was `List<Device>`, but you didn't specify the type of v.